# Is there a specification for the PCD file format?

Tags: specifications, point-cloud-library, file-format, point-clouds

Is there an official specification for the *point cloud data* (PCD) format? Or is it rather only intended for PCL-internal use? The only information I found about it is [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php) which kind of looks like a specification, but it doesn't contain all the information needed.

I might want to write a PCD loader library (independent of PCL), but maybe this is discouraged?

Comment: Looks like the specification you linked to is now here: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/pcd_file_format.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally, PCD files are mostly used in PCL-enabled applications written in C++. However, there are loaders implemented in other languages, for example [Python](https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd) and [JavaScript](https://gitlab.com/taketwo/three-pcd-loader), so it is definitely not just a PCL-internal format.

To my knowledge, there is no official specification besides the one you already linked. And indeed, it is incomplete, for instance the `binary_compressed` data storage format is not mentioned at all. I would suggest to use the PCL implementation (which is fairly stable) as a reference and resolve any ambiguities in the linked document by checking how the code works.